# java.lang.NullPointerException line 53

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I keep getting the null pointer exception error but im not sure how to fix it.  Below is my log cat.  I think the error is on line 53 of Second.java.  Below the log cat info is my code from my Second.java file.  Thanks for any help anyone can provide in fixing this error.

```
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ebonybutler.cammct/com.ebonybutler.cammct.Second}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1702)
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:974)
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     at com.ebonybutler.cammct.Second.onCreate(Second.java:53)
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1666)
10-11 13:39:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(7905):     ... 11 more
```

And here is my code:

```
package com.ebonybutler.cammct;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;


public class Second extends Activity {

//variable for selection intent
private final int PICKER = 1;
//variable to store the currently selected image
private int currentPic = 0;
//adapter for gallery view
private PicAdapter imgAdapt;     
//gallery object
private Gallery picGallery;
//image view for larger display
private ImageView picView;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //get the large image view
    picView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);

    //get the gallery view
    picGallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);

    //create a new adapter
    imgAdapt = new PicAdapter(this);
    //set the gallery adapter
    picGallery.setAdapter(imgAdapt);

    //set long click listener for each gallery thumbnail item
    picGallery.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
        //handle long clicks
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            //update the currently selected position so that we assign the imported bitmap to correct item
            currentPic = position;
            //take the user to their chosen image selection app (gallery or file manager)
            Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
            pickIntent.setType("image/*");
            pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, "Select Picture"), PICKER);
            return true;
        }
    });

    //set the click listener for each item in the thumbnail gallery
    picGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        //handles clicks
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int
                position, long id) {
            //set the larger image view to display the chosen bitmap calling method of adapter class
            picView.setImageBitmap(imgAdapt.getPic(position));
        }
    });
}

    //Base Adapter subclass creates Gallery view

        public class PicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            //use the default gallery background image
            int defaultItemBackground;
            //gallery context
            private Context galleryContext;
            //array to store bitmaps to display
            private Bitmap[] imageBitmaps;
            //place holder bitmap for empty spaces in gallery
            Bitmap placeholder;

            //constructor
            public PicAdapter(Context c){
                //instantiate context
                galleryContext = c;
                //create bitmap array
                imageBitmaps = new Bitmap[10];
                //decode the place holder image
                placeholder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                //more processing

                //set place holder as all thumb nail images in the gallery initially
                for(int i=0; i<imageBitmaps.length; i++)
                    imageBitmaps[i]= placeholder;

                //get the styling attributes - use default Android system resources
                TypedArray styleAttrs = galleryContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.PicGallery);
                //get the background resource
                defaultItemBackground = styleAttrs.getResourceId(R.styleable.PicGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
                //recycle attributes
                styleAttrs.recycle();

            }

            //BaseAdapter methods

        //return number of data items i.e. bitmap images
        public int getCount() {
        return imageBitmaps.length;
        }
        //return item t specified position
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //return item ID at specified position
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        //get view specifies layout and display options for each thumb nail in the gallery
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //create the view
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(galleryContext);
            //specify the bitmap at this position in the array
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmaps[position]);
            //set layout options
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(300, 200));
            //scale type within view area
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            //set default gallery item background
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(defaultItemBackground);
            //return the view
            return imageView;
        }

        //custom methods for this app
        //helper method to add a bitmap to the gallery when the user choose one

        public void addPic(Bitmap newPic)
        {
            //set at currently selected index
            imageBitmaps[currentPic] = newPic;
        }

        //return bitmap at specified position for larger display
        public Bitmap getPic(int posn)
        {
            //return bitmap at posn index
            return imageBitmaps[posn];
        }
        }
        //Handle returning from gallery or file manager image selection

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //check if we are returning from picture selection
                if(requestCode == PICKER) {

                    //the returned picture URI
                    Uri pickedUri = data.getData();

                    //declare the bitmap
                    Bitmap pic = null;
                    //declare the path string
                    String imgPath = "";

                    //retrieve the string using media data
                    String[] medData = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    //query the data
                    Cursor picCursor = managedQuery(pickedUri, medData, null, null, null);
                    if(picCursor!=null)
                    {
                        //get the path string
                        int index = picCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                        picCursor.moveToFirst();
                        imgPath = picCursor.getString(index);
                    }
                    else
                        imgPath = pickedUri.getPath();

                    //if and ese handle both choosing from gallery and from file manager

                    //if we have a new URI attempt to decode the image itmap
                    if(pickedUri!=null) {

                        //set the width and height we want to use as maximum display
                        int targetWidth = 600;
                        int targetHeight = 400;

                        //sample the incoming image to save on memory resources

                        //create bitmap options to calculate and use sample size
                        BitmapFactory.Options bmpOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                        //first decode image dimensions only - not the image bitmap itself
                        bmpOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, bmpOptions);

                        //work out what the sample size should be

                        //image width and height before sampling
                        int currHeight = bmpOptions.outHeight;
                        int currWidth = bmpOptions.outWidth;

                        //variable to store new sample size
                        int sampleSize = 1;

                        //calculate the sample size if the existing size is larger than target size

                        if (currHeight>targetHeight || currWidth>targetWidth)
                        {
                            //use either width of height
                            if (currWidth>currHeight)
                                sampleSize = Math.round((float)currHeight/(float)targetHeight);
                                else
                                    sampleSize = Math.round((float)currWidth/(float)targetWidth);

                        }
                        //use the new sample size
                        bmpOptions.inSampleSize = sampleSize;

                        //now decode the bitmap using sample options
                        bmpOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

                        //get the file as a bitmap
                        pic = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, bmpOptions);

                        //pass bitmap to ImageAdapter to add to array
                        imgAdapt.addPic(pic);
                        //redraw the gallery thumbnails to reflect the new addition
                        picGallery.setAdapter(imgAdapt);

                        //display the newly selected image at larger size
                        picView.setImageBitmap(pic);
                        //scale options
                        picView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

                    }
                }
            }
            //superclass method
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:text="@string/select_intro"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:textStyle="bold"/>

<Gallery
   android:id="@+id/gallery"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:textStyle="italic"
   android:text="@string/show_intro"/>

<ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/picture"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:contentDescription="@string/picture"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is line 53 in your code?

Comment: is your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Hi Nick, I thought that was it too.  I added the .Second in the activity section and it was a no go.

Answer (score 2):

Line 53 is:

```
picGallery.setAdapter(imgAdapt);
```

so check what is being returned from

```
picGallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'what its being returned from'? Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Comment: The `picGallery` variable is not being set here resulting in an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try debugging it? Try debug mode in Eclipse and place a breakpoint at row 53.

At row 53 you seem to have:

```
picGallery.setAdapter(imgAdapt);
```

Now you can't call a set operation on picGallery if it's null. so you might want to check for that.

```
if (picGallery == null) {
// do something useful, perhaps set it? I'm not familiar with android
}
```

Now by the looks of things picGallery is supposed to get set earlier on.

```
picGallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
```

Might want to look into why findViewById returned null.